What is the driving force behind individuals ideas of opinion being factual?
It is evident upon observation that individuals will tend to argue for a completely subjective viewpoint regarding all of existence. In fact, in truth, the triviality regarding subjectivity ultimately provokes a "I'm using subjectivity solely to cater to my preferences" mentality. Thusly, it is seemingly required in order to defend "tastes, ideas, etc."
Now, the biggest issue with this is that we start to work from an inside out perspective in regard to the big questions, whereas logically, it seems we should start from a "outside-in" perception. Implying that we gain a greater understanding of ourselves when we properly understand why we even exist, how we even exist, furthermore what is at the foundation, initially of our existence, which I would argue is essence.
In fact, I do hold the understanding that essence precedes existence, that energy, non-physical energy, is prior to the physical state. Thusly, this allows for all information to be of the non-physical state prior to the physical state being exercised in an attempt to understand itself. Based upon this acknowledgment, it is logically deductible that we do not require the opinion in order to comprehend who and what we are.
Similar to Buddhist philosophy, it is implying that we may live a life of "passivity", suggesting that it is easier to understand our "hows" and "whys" when we "reflect" inward, thusly attuning to the essence that is within ourselves. It seems to I, that this understanding requires no opinion, rather, the absence of opinion is truly required in order for all to understand the root of the philosophy itself.
This is precisely why I ask, what is the root cause of opinion being the driving force of our existence?
Surely, it is not consciousness, as consciousness cannot even be "properly" understood via the physical sciences, as it operates outside of the locale that is the brain. This can be understood properly so long as we do not retain the opinion that all of life is purely physical. Furthermore, this does not require a belief in the slightest, rather, the eradication of belief to understand that we may objectively attune ourselves to essence, to ensure that we understand, essentially, the foundation of our physicality.
Secondly, it couldn't logically be preference either. The reason is simple, we may all acknowledge our preferences and still understand the truth of our existence objectively. I prefer sunshine over rain, you prefer rain over sunshine. Both of these preferences do not imply a need to reject the "why" and "how" we exist.
I'd like to suggest that the opinion is not tied directly to our "true self" the "I" self, the Ego, rather, it is tied to the "false self" the "me" self, the ego. (Note: Ego = I; ego = me.)
Thusly, I ask again, what is the reason, the root cause, for the flooding of opinions that claim to be progressive and factual, yet, reject the fact that our essential drive for understanding of who and what we are, is not in identity of ego, rather understanding of Ego in accord with our initials, such things, or expressions, being metaphysical, or non-physical by nature?

The reason we start from our own perspective is simply that we are more familiar with it and can be more cogent. We can, and should, then expand our horizons and move away from parochial views and arguments. But the idea that we can understand 'big', more complex and remote, things before understanding 'little' things first is highly dubious, even if it is 'logical' in some abstract sense. Whether essence 'precedes' existence, or vice versa, is a completely different question from whether physical or non-physical is more fundamental, and as of now we do not know which for a fact.

Frw people deeply understand a lot of the areas you are asking about. Expecting people who haven't studied something and aren't particularly interested is not going to be fruitful. Like drinking water only due to thirst, people think only when necessary and to the extent that addresses the issue. Few people really understand water, despite consuming tons of it a year. They don't have to. Have you seen on TV where people ask passersby on the street very obvious questions and most people don't know the answers?

Let’s clarify some details: First, it should be understood that I’m asking for perception, not perspective. For example, the Kosmos, is not reliant on perspective in order to exist, rather, it is perception that allows for the Kosmos to function as a “living entity”. If the Kosmos were to be perspective based, we wouldn’t be able to understand anything within such as stars, our planet or even the sun/moon. Second, this is philosophy, if you can’t handle questions that make you seemingly uncomfortable because they shake your opinion, please leave. Thanks.

I will strongly debate applying the term "passive" to the Buddhist philosophy.

the flooding of opinions that claim to be progressive and factual

Isn't that the neutral way of saying "those who I don't agree with"? Man, that's ego speaks in you. Why would you even care about other opinions, even if they claim to be not simply "progressive and factual" buy "The True AND ONLY GOD".
Idk, you question is so wide, that I feel strange sympathy.
When I started to get involved in philosophy, I was met with some revelations over and over again. I think we all can agree that we study all this in order to stay in the process of enjoyment. Such a supreme all-encompassing sense of the special value of our occupation.
Despite the fact that the study of metaphysics has really opened my eyes to many things (or to the core of all things), for me it became an excuse to escape from my daily routine into that ideal neoplatonic world of absolute abstractions. I spent couple of years debating with myself, even if I lived in the city of 1M+ people.
So, the main lesson - I live on earth, which means that those cool things which exists in the world of abstractions - like what is "essence" or "substance" - it has little to do with the reality around me, because to say that "I know something about (insert any actual thing which you encounter here)" is the height of arrogance.
If I know that 1+2+3+4=10, it give no authority to enforce this abstract rule to the some Australian Aborigines who only can count up to 2. That's not because they bad, or stupid, or their opinion is broken, it is the challenge of "can I using learn their Creole language and introduce the idea of 3 to them". This is how fun is made, of course, if you like adventures.
So my frenzied desire to know some unknown Ego can only serve as a compass or a map. "wishing to know Ego" and "Ego" are not the same.
Anyway, if there are a lot of different opinions, where all they located? Aren't these just images in your head? That's how it turned out for me. Dozens of different egos are arguing about which path to Ego is the (best, correct, rational, truthy).
One day, a girl said to me: "You are an essential freak". Of course, I doubt that she even had an approximate understanding of what "essential" actually means. With the feeling with which this was said, it was clear that this was not the place for high philosophical discussions about the essence of being.
It's more about the breadth of my consciousness, whether I can call a black thing a white and a white thing a black thing without losing that metaphysical reference point, that white is actual white and black is actual black.
So the main point is, even if the metaphysic laws are indestructible and indisputable, the physic nature of the world we live apply. I decided that I have to put my mind into my heart, and try to feel it all in action. And all I have to say - man the world of physics is absolute chaos but it's the only way to the so-desired state of "being-here-and-now" where everything is visible as it is.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
